# Collision detection bug

Tags: java, 2d, collision-detection

I've tried to expand a little on my enemy spawning system using the factory design pattern.

So I have: Enemy (abstract): EnemyTyp eA, B, C, D... etc., each of which extend Enemy.

I have this: (works)

```
public void spawnEnemy(int type, int amount) {

    Enemy theEnemy =  null;
    for (int i=1; i<amount+1; i++ ) {
        theEnemy = enemyFactory.makeEnemy(type, 0-i*40, 400);
        aliens.add(theEnemy);
        health.add(2);
        System.out.println("Attack Message Recieved "+i);
    }
    repaint();
}
```

But I cannot seem to get collision detection to work.

```
public void checkCollisions() {  
           Rectangle r3 = player.getBounds();
           ArrayList ms = player.getMissiles();
           for (int i = 0; i < ms.size(); i++) {
                Missile m = (Missile) ms.get(i);
                Rectangle r1 = m.getBounds();

                for (int j = 0; j<aliens.size(); j++) {
                    Enemy a = (Enemy) aliens.get(j);
                    Rectangle r2 = a.getBounds();

                    if (r1.intersects(r2)) {
                        m.setVisible(false);
                        a.setHealth(-1);
                        if(a.getHealth()==0){
                        a.setVisible(false);
                        }

                }}


            }
        }
```

I believe it's because I am turning it back into an Enemy (abstract) and that is why I am getting no collision.. So when I take the item back out of the ArrayList how can I take out the exact enemytype I put in originally in the `spawnEnemy()` method? Use the `theEnemy` variable and a combination of `instanceOf`? I am extremely confused.

Comment: So long as your subclasses are correctly reporting there bounds, it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Missle detects the collision and goes off the screen.. but the actual enemy does not and still stays on the screne

Comment: So if the detection is working, what is happening with the health.  A debugger is going to help you here